# Regular Expression Help Needed - Advanced Search and Replace

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like

```
"'Joe'&@[Uk Customers.First Name](contact:16[[---]]first_name) +@[Uk Customers.Last Name](contact:16[[---]]last_name)"
```

My requirement is start finding the pattern

```
@[A.B](contact:**digit**[[---]]**field**)
```

There can be many pattern in single string.

and replace it with a new string (entire pattern should be replaced) with a dynamic text generated by **digit** and **field** value

For an example for above string there are two matches

1st match is : array(**digit** => 16, **field** =>first_name)

2nd match is : array(**digit** => 16, **field** =>last_name)

and somewhere I have few rules which are

if digit is 16 and field is first_name replace pattern with "John" 
if digit is 16 and field is last_name replace pattern with "Doe"

so the output string will be "'Joe'&John+Doe"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matching part is fairly straightforward. This will do the trick:

```
@\[[^.]+\.[^.]+\]\(contact:(\d+)\[\[---\]\]([^)]+)\)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/igWjFn0G00kXUwmV)

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nL4jY1)

In PHP (and other languages that support named capture groups), you can do this to get the array to contain keys "digit" and "field":

```
@\[[^.]+\.[^.]+\]\(contact:(?<digit>\d+)\[\[---\]\](?<field>[^)]+)\)
```

Example PHP code:

```
$regex = '/@\[[^.]+\.[^.]+\]\(contact:(?<digit>\d+)\[\[---\]\](?<field>[^)]+)\)/';
$text = '"\'Joe\'&@[Uk Customers.First Name](contact:16[[---]]first_name) +@[Uk Customers.Last Name](contact:16[[---]]last_name)"';


preg_match_all($regex, $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

var_dump($matches);
```

Result:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(55) "@[Uk Customers.First Name](contact:16[[---]]first_name)"
    ["digit"]=>
    string(2) "16"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "16"
    ["field"]=>
    string(10) "first_name"
    [2]=>
    string(10) "first_name"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(53) "@[Uk Customers.Last Name](contact:16[[---]]last_name)"
    ["digit"]=>
    string(2) "16"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "16"
    ["field"]=>
    string(9) "last_name"
    [2]=>
    string(9) "last_name"
  }
}
```

I'm not real clear on the logic you want to use for the replacement, so I'm afraid I can't help there without some clarification.

Comment: + 1 for detailed solution :)